# Anchor element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where does the value go when an event handler assigned to an onclick event of anchor element returns any value .for example:

```
<a href="some.htm"  id="maiz">
<script>
function test(){return x=5;}
document.getElementById("maiz").onclick=test;

<script>
```

will the element receives the value if so how can i access it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No code is waiting for the return value from an event handler except the event mechanism. So, there is no way you can get the return value and process it.

Using `return false;` inside an event handler cancels the event. For example:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Cancelling Hyperlinks</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<A HREF="c:" onclick="return false;">C drive</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It is equivalent to

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

Read more [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/advanced-javascript-event-handling.html)...

**Update**

Events which uses the return value:

```
onclick of HREF:
return false cancels navigation after the code is executed

onsubmit of form
return false cancels submission of the form
```

Comment: how can u say that event handler only returns boolean value

Comment: @Maizere Because that is the only value understood by the event handling mechanism.

Comment: @Maizere: He didn’t phrase it properly, but he’s essentially right: the event handler’s return value is evaluated as if it were a boolean: if it’s a _[truthy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/)_ value, the event continues; if it’s a _falsy_ value, the event is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

In general you access a return value of the method is as shown below.

```
function test(){return x=5;}

var result = test();
```

You can only return true / false to an event, which thereby stops the execution of further events.